# Obtaining a file list from FTP

Tags: batch-file, text, ftp, automation, export

I currently have this file which obtains a list of files within an FTP directory and outputs it to a .txt file:

```
del list.txt
cls

echo user *user*>> ftp.dat
echo *pass*>> ftp.dat
echo lcd C:\TEST>> ftp.dat
echo cd dir>> ftp.dat
echo ls * list.txt>> ftp.dat
echo bye>> ftp.dat

ftp.exe -n -s:ftp.dat *server*
del ftp.dat
```

This will return a list of file names which is brilliant, however I would also like to obtain their last modified dates. Does anyone know of anyway to change my current batch file to do this, or even a way of accomplishing the same thing (running a file which just dumps the data in a text file) using a different method?

Thank you in advanced,
Daniel Osborne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dir` instead of `ls` to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls --full-time` which will also print the last modified date for each file.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I just tried this and it doesn't seem to work, this is the output:

ftp> ls * --full-time list.txt
Usage: ls remote directory local file.

Comment: I see your question has been already answered :) Usually the ftp ls command provides the same options as the unix ls command. It seems that this is not the case here, though. I think this depends on the ftp server implementation.